# Can't override custom comparison in SQLAlchemy symmetrically

Tags: python, datetime, sqlalchemy

I've been trying to implement a datetime-style field in SQL Alchemy that, in the database backend, uses a specific ISO-8601 format (e.g. "2013-04-30T00:26:03.000+05:00"), and is a datetime at the Python end. The primary database engine is MySQL.

I don't want to implement this as a hybrid property, because I want a lot of these fields and to be able to use them automatically. I've implemented a TypeDecorator with a custom comparator (code below). This works fine for the following operations:

- save from Python to database
- load from database to Python
- compare database column to literal, either as (DateTimeAsIsoText op LITERAL), or (LITERAL op DateTimeAsIsoText)
- compare DateTimeAsIsoText column to another column of the same type
- compare DateTimeAsIsoText to DATETIME
- ... but **not** DATETIME to DateTimeAsIsoText.

I'm stuck because the comparator's operate() function isn't called in this situation, it seems, and neither is its reverse_operate() function.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import datetime
import dateutil.parser
import getpass
import logging
import pytz
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    DateTime,
    Integer,
    String,
    TypeDecorator
)
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import func

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())

Base = declarative_base()


# =============================================================================
# Ancillary functions
# =============================================================================

def heading(x):
    print("=" * 79)
    print(x)
    print("=" * 79)


def ask_user(prompt, default=None, returntype=None, mask=False):
    if default is not None:
        fullprompt = "{} [{}]: ".format(prompt, default)
    else:
        fullprompt = "{}: ".format(prompt)
    success = False
    while not success:
        if mask:
            value = getpass.getpass(fullprompt) or default
        else:
            value = input(fullprompt) or default
        if returntype is not None:
            try:
                value = returntype(value)
                success = True
            except:
                print("Bad value, try again")
        else:
            success = True
    return value


def engine_mysql(user, password, host, port, database, echo=True,
                 interface="pymysql"):
    CONNECTSTRING = (
        "mysql+{interface}://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/"
        "{database}".format(
            interface=interface,
            user=user,
            password=password,
            host=host,
            port=port,
            database=database
        ))
    # Removed "?charset=utf8&use_unicode=0"; with PyMySQL==0.7.1 it causes
    # TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
    # because dates come back as e.g. b'2013-05-30 06:00:00' and then the
    # convert_datetime function in pymysql/converters.py chokes.
    return sqlalchemy.create_engine(CONNECTSTRING, echo=echo)


def engine_mysql_commandline(echo=True):
    host = ask_user("Host", "localhost")
    port = 3306
    database = ask_user("Database", "testdb")
    user = ask_user("User", "root")
    password = ask_user("Password", mask=True)
    return engine_mysql(user, password, host, port, database, echo=echo)


# =============================================================================
# Custom date/time field as ISO-8601 text including timezone
# =============================================================================

def python_datetime_to_iso(x):
    """From a Python datetime to an ISO-formatted string in our particular
    format."""
    # https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior  # noqa
    try:
        mainpart = x.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")  # microsecond accuracy
        timezone = x.strftime("%z")  # won't have the colon in
        return mainpart + timezone[:-2] + ":" + timezone[-2:]
    except AttributeError:
        return None


def iso_to_python_datetime(x):
    """From an ISO-formatted string to a Python datetime, with timezone."""
    try:
        return dateutil.parser.parse(x)
    except (AttributeError, ValueError):
        return None


def python_datetime_to_utc(x):
    """From a Python datetime, with timezone, to a UTC Python version."""
    try:
        return x.astimezone(pytz.utc)
    except AttributeError:
        return None


def mysql_isotzdatetime_to_utcdatetime(x):
    """Creates an SQL expression wrapping a field containing our ISO-8601 text,
    making a DATETIME out of it, in the UTC timezone."""
    # For format, see
    #   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format  # noqa
    # Note the use of "%i" for minutes.
    # Things after "func." get passed to the database engine as literal SQL
    # functions; http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html
    return func.CONVERT_TZ(
        func.STR_TO_DATE(
            func.LEFT(x, func.LENGTH(x) - 6),
            '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%S.%f'
        ),
        func.RIGHT(x, 6),
        "+00:00"
    )


def mysql_unknown_field_to_utcdatetime(x):
    """The field might be a DATETIME, or an ISO-formatted field."""
    return func.IF(
        func.LENGTH(x) == 19,
        # ... length of a plain DATETIME e.g. 2013-05-30 00:00:00
        x,
        mysql_isotzdatetime_to_utcdatetime(x)
    )


class DateTimeAsIsoText(TypeDecorator):
    '''Stores date/time values as ISO-8601.'''
    impl = sqlalchemy.types.String(32)  # underlying SQL type

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        """Convert things on the way from Python to the database."""
        logger.debug(
            "process_bind_param(self={}, value={}, dialect={})".format(
                repr(self), repr(value), repr(dialect)))
        return python_datetime_to_iso(value)

    def process_literal_param(self, value, dialect):
        """Convert things on the way from Python to the database."""
        logger.debug(
            "process_literal_param(self={}, value={}, dialect={})".format(
                repr(self), repr(value), repr(dialect)))
        return python_datetime_to_iso(value)

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        """Convert things on the way from the database to Python."""
        logger.debug(
            "process_result_value(self={}, value={}, dialect={})".format(
                repr(self), repr(value), repr(dialect)))
        return iso_to_python_datetime(value)

    class comparator_factory(TypeDecorator.Comparator):
        """Process SQL for when we are comparing our column, in the database,
        to something else."""
        def operate(self, op, other):
            if isinstance(other, datetime.datetime):
                processed_other = python_datetime_to_utc(other)
            else:
                # OK. At this point, "other" could be a plain DATETIME field,
                # or a DateTimeAsIsoText field (or potentially something
                # else that we don't really care about). If it's a DATETIME,
                # then we assume it is already in UTC.
                processed_other = mysql_unknown_field_to_utcdatetime(other)
            logger.debug("operate(self={}, op={}, other={})".format(
                repr(self), repr(op), repr(other)))
            logger.debug("self.expr = {}".format(repr(self.expr)))
            # traceback.print_stack()
            return op(mysql_isotzdatetime_to_utcdatetime(self.expr),
                      processed_other)
            # NOT YET IMPLEMENTED: dialects other than MySQL, and how to
            # detect the dialect at this point.

        def reverse_operate(self, op, other):
            assert False, "I don't think this is ever being called"


class TestIso(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test_iso_datetime'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(20))
    plain_datetime = Column(DateTime)
    when_created = Column(DateTimeAsIsoText)
    when_deleted = Column(DateTimeAsIsoText)

    def __repr__(self):
        return (
            "<TestIso(id={}, name={}, "
            "plain_datetime={}, when_created={}, when_deleted={})>".format(
                self.id, self.name,
                repr(self.plain_datetime),
                repr(self.when_created), repr(self.when_deleted),
                self.q1)
        )


# =============================================================================
# Main, with unit testing
# =============================================================================

def test():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

    engine = engine_mysql_commandline(echo=True)
    engine.connect()
    Session = sessionmaker()
    Session.configure(bind=engine)  # once engine is available
    session = Session()
    # Create tables
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Unit testing for DateTimeAsIsoText
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    # Insert things
    t0_str = "2013-04-30T00:26:03.000+05:00"  # previous month
    t1_str = "2013-05-30T03:26:00.000+01:00"  # Sweden
    t2_str = "2013-05-30T03:00:00.000+00:00"  # London
    t3_str = "2013-05-30T01:00:00.000-05:00"  # New York
    t2b_str = "2013-05-30T04:00:00.000+01:00"  # equals t2

    t0 = dateutil.parser.parse(t0_str)
    t1 = dateutil.parser.parse(t1_str)
    t2 = dateutil.parser.parse(t2_str)
    t3 = dateutil.parser.parse(t3_str)
    t2b = dateutil.parser.parse(t2b_str)

    # t1 -> t3 decrease lexically, but increase temporally
    assert t1_str > t2_str > t3_str
    assert t0 < t1 < t2 == t2b < t3

    session.query(TestIso).delete()
    alice = TestIso(id=1, name="alice",
                    when_created=t1, when_deleted=t2,
                    plain_datetime=python_datetime_to_utc(t3))
    session.add(alice)
    bob = TestIso(id=2, name="bob",
                  when_created=t2, when_deleted=t3,
                  plain_datetime=python_datetime_to_utc(t0))
    session.add(bob)
    celia = TestIso(id=3, name="celia",
                    when_created=t3, when_deleted=t2,
                    plain_datetime=python_datetime_to_utc(t1))
    session.add(celia)
    david = TestIso(id=4, name="david",
                    when_created=t3, when_deleted=t3,
                    plain_datetime=python_datetime_to_utc(t1))
    session.add(david)
    edgar = TestIso(id=5, name="edgar",
                    when_created=t2b, when_deleted=t2,
                    plain_datetime=python_datetime_to_utc(t2b))
    session.add(edgar)
    session.commit()

    heading("DateTimeAsIsoText test: DateTimeAsIsoText field VERSUS literal")
    q = session.query(TestIso).filter(TestIso.when_created < t2)
    assert q.all() == [alice]
    q = session.query(TestIso).filter(TestIso.when_created == t2)
    assert q.all() == [bob, edgar]
    q = session.query(TestIso).filter(TestIso.when_created > t2)
    assert q.all() == [celia, david]

    heading("DateTimeAsIsoText test: literal VERSUS DateTimeAsIsoText field")
    q = session.query(TestIso).filter(t2 > TestIso.when_created)
    assert q.all() == [alice]
    q = session.query(TestIso).filter(t2 == TestIso.when_created)
    assert q.all() == [bob, edgar]
    q = session.query(TestIso).filter(t2 < TestIso.when_created)
    assert q.all() == [celia, david]

    heading("DateTimeAsIsoText test: DateTimeAsIsoText field VERSUS "
            "DateTimeAsIsoText field")
    q = session.query(TestIso).filter(TestIso.when_created <
                                      TestIso.when_deleted)
    assert q.all() == [alice, bob]
    q = session.query(TestIso).filter(TestIso.when_created ==
                                      TestIso.when_deleted)
    assert q.all() == [david, edgar]
    q = session.query(TestIso).filter(TestIso.when_created >
                                      TestIso.when_deleted)
    assert q.all() == [celia]

    heading("DateTimeAsIsoText test: DateTimeAsIsoText field VERSUS "
            "plain DATETIME field")
    q = session.query(TestIso).filter(TestIso.when_created <
                                      TestIso.plain_datetime)
    assert q.all() == [alice]
    q = session.query(TestIso).filter(TestIso.when_created ==
                                      TestIso.plain_datetime)
    # CAUTION: don't have any non-zero millisecond components; they'll get
    # stripped from the plain DATETIME and exact comparisons will then fail.
    assert q.all() == [edgar]
    q = session.query(TestIso).filter(TestIso.when_created >
                                      TestIso.plain_datetime)
    assert q.all() == [bob, celia, david]

    heading("DateTimeAsIsoText testplain DATETIME field VERSUS "
            "DateTimeAsIsoText field")
    q = session.query(TestIso).filter(TestIso.plain_datetime >
                                      TestIso.when_created)
    assert q.all() == [alice]
    q = session.query(TestIso).filter(TestIso.plain_datetime ==
                                      TestIso.when_created)
    assert q.all() == [edgar]
    q = session.query(TestIso).filter(TestIso.plain_datetime <
                                      TestIso.when_created)
    assert q.all() == [bob, celia, david]

    heading("DateTimeAsIsoText test: SELECT everything")
    q = session.query(TestIso)
    assert q.all() == [alice, bob, celia, david, edgar]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Results

- All comparisons work, except the last set of comparisons, of a plain DATETIME field to a DateTimeAsIsoText field *(in that order)*.

Am I missing something obvious?